# Change settings on VS Code to be like Sublime Text

Tags: python, pygame, sublimetext3

I am a beginner programmer so please bear with me.
In Sublime Text, pygame finds the images on the folder (which can be specified) in which the .py file is located in. Example:

```py
pygame.image.load("data/magnifying_glass.png")
```

In VS Code, you have to set the current working directory to a folder, which would be where your images (or .tiff) files are located. It would look messy if image files from every projects are located in one folder.  Tried *os.path.join* but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **open a folder**. It can be done from *File* -> *Open Folder* from the top menu. You can also use the key combination `Ctrl + K,  Ctrl + O`.  Then choose your current working directory (not file). Click open and your files should be here. It means you need a project folder.